# Trying to add numbers with a function

Tags: python, list, function

```
def listsum(numList):
    if len(numList) == 1:
        print(numList[0])
    else:
         print(numList[0]+listsum(numList[1:]))
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    lit1=[1, 2,  3, 4, 5]
    listsum(lit1)
```

I need help with this code, I am getting:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'.

I am trying to add all the enumbers in a list

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType' means that you are trying to do an operation of `+` and that this operation isn't supported between integers and Nones. That should point you in the right direction. Find the part of your code where you're doing a `+` and figure out why one of the left or right hand side (it's the right hand side) of that operation is yielding a None. The answer to the question is supplied by Mureinik below (there's no return from your function)

Comment: See if you can figure out what the error says. It says one of the things you're adding is an `int` and the other is `None`. Which of those two is the `None`? Why is that? Can you fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of printing the sum, you should just return it, and leave the printing to the caller:

```py
def listsum(numList):
    if len(numList) == 1:
        return numList[0]
    else:
         return numList[0] + listsum(numList[1:])
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    lit1=[1, 2,  3, 4, 5]
    print(listsum(lit1))
```